# How to make collection of the galleries on same page in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, gallery, drupal-views

I need to have page that is collection of the galleries. Every gallery has to be represent by one image. When user click on that image whole gallery that image represents should open. And the same thing for every image. Something like on this [site](http://www.gdeizaci.com/slike-klubova).

Of course there is non elegant way where for every gallery we have to make new content type, and views for each of it. But I want to make it easy for client to add new gallerias, without building views every time. Is there a module that makes collection of galleries. If someone want to help me and lead me step by step it would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [Node gallery module](https://drupal.org/project/node_gallery),

> The Node Gallery module allows you to create multimedia galleries
>   where both the galleries and the gallery items are nodes. (as opposed
>   to gallery items being file fields, like Media Gallery)

[Check the demo here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-zw6yR4dZM)